# Enable spelling in code files outside of comments

Tags: spell-checking

I've got the following obviously misspelled file:

```
bla blar blar
```

When I open it as "bla.txt" and run `:setlocal spell` vim rightly points out all three words as misspellings. However, if I `mv` the file to `bla.js` and open it again, turning on spelling does not highlight anything. It will select spelling mistakes inside of comments, however. Is there a way to enable spell checking of, say, string literals (or everything?)

Comment: At a guess, the syntax for JS disabled spell checking in many of its syntax elements (usually comments are the only things that get spell checked in code)

Comment: Where would one go to configure that? I notice that the help says: `Files that use syntax highlighting can specify where spell checking should be
done` so there's got to be a way.

Comment: Also, confirmed that it checks spelling in comments; will update question title.

Answer (score 3):

`$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/javascript.vim` has some syntax items (specifically, the comments) which `contains=@Spell`. Therefore, if user sets both `syntax on` and `set spell`, only such items will be spell-checked, as explained in `:h spell-syntax`.

To override this you have to issue the command:

```
syntax spell toplevel
```

See `:h syn-spell` for more info.

Also note that simply deleting `.vimrc` leaves filetypes / syntax on, as Vim uses `$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim` in this case. So always run `vim --clean` when trying to check the true defaults.

Comment: Eh, the js files dont set syntax on—users do. Minor nit though.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I stand corrected.